Disable physical button presses activating QR reader Chainway C72
I am writing an app on Chainway C72 that uses both QR code reader and UHF reader.
I need to use physical buttons to scan using both modules (in app user can swith a module and I need to activate only one scanner on key press at a time). I use RFID with RFIDWithUHFUART class and QR using BarcodeUtility class. For QR other classes either not work or cause ANR. I can access physical button events using Activity onKeyUp and onKeyDown methods, but QR scanner activates when I press the button. Is there a way to disable it? Disabling QR reader while switching to RFID works, but it doesn't seem like a good solution and can cause problems, because QR already works half of the time.
I tried using ScannerUtility to activate RFID, but it doesn't work.
I used ScannerUtility class and called
utility.setScanKey(context, 3, intArrayOf(293, 139)) to activate buttons for RFID
but it works only for QR.
Also I tried disabling buttons by calling utility.setScanKey(context, 0, intArrayOf()) and
utility.setScanKey(context, 0, null) but it doesn't work also.

did you ever found the solution? i'm facing the same issue
